# How to extract only a certain text from a file

Tags: javascript, jenkins, groovy, svn, jenkins-pipeline

so I have a file called "versions.properties", which looks like this-

```
#ccsmp build version information
#Tue, 12 Apr 2022 15:32:37 -0400
branch.type=feature
cscsmp.svn.branch=branches/features/javarto_maven
ivy.cache.dir.name=${svn.branch}
jrto.version=${jrto.version.major}.${jrto.version.minor}.${jrto.version.maintenance}
jrto.version.build=26856
jrto.version.maintenance=0
jrto.version.major=0
jrto.version.minor=0
lib.version=1.5
openvms_pass=xyz
openvms_server=xyz
openvms_user=loadxyz
svn.branch=branches/features/CRE-442
svn.branchurl=${svn.rooturl}/${svn.branch}
svn.password=xyz
svn.rooturl=svn\://xyz-repo/svn/ccsmp
svn.tagurl=${svn.rooturl}/tags
svn.username=xyz
version.build=846
version.date=2022/04/12 15\:32
version.maintenance=0
version.major=1
version.minor=37
version.release=${version.major}.${version.minor}.${version.maintenance}.${version.build}
```

I am trying to read this file and then by using the values of **version.major, version.minor, version.maintenance, version.build**

I want to feed these values into following-

def SVN_TAG=ccsmp_v_${version.major}.${version.minor}.${version.maintenance}.${version.build}

So when I do `println ${SVN_TAG}`

It outputs -

```
SVN_TAG=ccsmp_v_1.37.0.846
```

Is there any way to do this? Any suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: "Sorry I should have mentioned this before, I am using a very old version of svn(1.6.23_32) and jenkins, therefore, it doesn't have latest plugins. Also, I cant use git, as my jenkins dont support this fully. I have to use something that use simple read file argument." is a comment that the OP left on an answer I have since deleted because it doesn't satisfy the requirement.  This information may be helpful.

Comment: I do not think that the version of svn you are using will affect the solution.  Can you clarify what it is that you mean by "I have to use something that use a simple read file argument"?

Comment: So im trying to use something similar to the answer given by @daggett

Comment: But I tried both of his solutions but they didnt worked

Comment: "But I tried both of his solutions but they didnt worked " - I am sorry that I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
def p = readProperties file: 'versions.properties'

def SVN_TAG="ccsmp_v_${p.version.major}.${p.version.minor}.${p.version.maintenance}.${p.version.build}"
```

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readproperties-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text

If you don't have readProperties

```js
//declare function with non cps
@NonCPS
def toProperties(String s){
  p = new Properties()
  p.load( new StringReader(s) )
  return p
}


def p = readFile 'versions.properties'
p = toProperties(p)
def SVN_TAG="ccsmp_v_${p.'version.major'}.${p.'version.minor'}..."
```

or another option with parsing each line

```js
@NonCPS
def toProperties(String s){
  s.readLines().collect{it.split('=')}.findAll{it.size()==2}.collectEntries()
}

//the rest is the same as above
```

Comment: I got the following error when I ran this - `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'readProperties' found among [ansiColor, archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, error, fileExists, git, input, isUnix, load, mail, node, parallel, properties, publishHTML, pwd, readFile, retry, sh, slackSend, sleep, sshagent, stage, stash, step, svn, timeout, timestamps, tool, unarchive, unstash, waitUntil, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws]`

Comment: Try to install it. There is a link to plugin in documentation.

Comment: I am not allowed to install any new plugins on the jenkins server, as our company's jenkins server is very old and it has some important jobs running that only works with the older version.

Comment: Updated the answer, but there is a chance that you have to use @NonCPS because string reader is non serializable...

Comment: So I did this


`@NonCPS
  def p = readFile 'tools/versions.properties'
  p = new Properties().load( new StringReader(p) )
  def SVN_TAG="ccsmp_v_${p.version.major}.${p.version.minor}.${p.version.maintenance}.${p.version.build}"`



But I got the following error-



`java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'version' on null object`

Comment: oh, i missed that accessor should be a bit different. updated the answer ^^^